# Topological insulators

Tags: homework-and-exercises, topological-insulators

https://arxiv.org/abs/1504.05280 in this paper author derived numerically orbital magnetization of 2d thin topological insulators say graphene like system numerically. I have tried to reproduce this for several days the fig 3 plot of this paper but could not get to find orbital magnetization of the order 10^-3.Another thing how author has claimed orbital magnetization unit to be Tesla. How could this be possible? It should be amp/length in dimension.

Anyone have solve this paper? Or could give me any suggestion of the code they to solve the sum of eqn 6 and eqn 7?

Comment: Please clarify explicitly and in a self-contained manner (not by reference to a paper) where you have issues. I don’t think you can expect people to read a manuscript in order to understand your question.

Comment: I've changed the link you gave to the pdf file to the abstract page instead.  This is the preferred way to link to paper on Physics SE.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the authors are actually plotting $\tilde{M}_{orb} = \mu_0 ~M_{orb}$.

Since \begin{align}
[M_{orb}] = A / m,
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
[\mu_0] = H / m,
\end{align}
it's easy to see that
\begin{align}
[\tilde{M}_{orb}] = H \cdot A / m^2,
\end{align}
which is, by definition, a Tesla.

Since $\mu_0 \approx 1.26 \times 10^{-6}$, this could account account for the difference in orbital magnetization values. You should get values of the order of $\tilde{M}_{orb} \approx 10^{-3}$ if your $M_{orb}$ is on the order of $10^3~A/m$.

Comment: Thanks for showing your interest on this question. I am getting Morb values 10^-16 not 10^3. I can attach my python code here if you want. And how can you say that Morb here is multiplied by mu(not) ? From where this mu(not) is coming in equation provided here? Another question here is how they find m(k) here in this paper is also my doubt.

Comment: I'm supposing they multiplied $M_{orb}$ by $\mu_0$ because it seems the most sensible way to get a quantity that has units of Tesla.